# Don't understand this C loop

Tags: c, while-loop

Can anyone explain to me how does this loop works? I understand that the first operator counts its remainder, the second counts its division result, but I can't understand how does it sum them using the loop? Here's the code:

```c
// Calculate the sum of the digits of the number N.

int N, S, Z;
S = 0;

printf("Input N\n");
scanf("%d", &N);

while(N != 0) {
    Z = N % 10;
    N = N / 10;
    S = S + Z;
}
printf("Sum = %d\n", S);
```

Comment: Basically, it is just splitting the number up into separate digits and then adding them all together..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This while loop adds all the digit of your number referred in by N. It add's all the digit by taking remainder of number when divided by 10. And everytime, it eliminates the last digit of the number. So if your number is 326, it will work like:

```
 326 != 0
     Z = 6
     N = 32
     S = 6
         32 != 0
             Z = 2
             N = 3
             S = 8
                 3 != 0
                     Z = 3
                     N = 0
                     S = 11
                         0 == 0 come out of loop
  print value of S i.e. 11
```

Comment: Glad it helped you understanding.

Answer (score 4):

It's basically a ***sum of digits*** of an integer number.

Example:

input ==> 1234

output ==> 4+ 3+ 2 + 1 = 10

***Code Break down:***

Initialize `S` [sum] to `0`.

*Loop:*

1. `Z = N % 10;` , store the remainder of `N` after `%10` into `Z`.
2. `N = N / 10;` , divide the contents on `N` by 10 and store the result back in `N`.
3. `S = S + Z;`, sum the content of `S` with the value in `Z`.

after that, check the modified value of `N` is 0 or not. If not, continue [1,2,3..)

Suggestion:

Always check the success of `scanf("%d", &N);`. If by any chance, `scanf()` fails, your code is trying to access uninitialized variable `N`, which may very well lead to undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Let's for a example take 657:

```
Z = N % 10;     // This line will store 7 in Z

N = N / 10;     // this line will convert N to 65

S = S + Z;      // and finally this line will add 0+7
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop will execute until the n value become zero.  For example

N=123

Then the first time values of the variables is
Z:3 : N:12 : S:3

Second time 
Z:2 : N:1  : S:5

Third time 
Z:1 : N:0 : S:6

Finally the answer of S will be 3+2+1=6.